# Solrj RuntimeException: First tuple is not a metadata tuple

Tags: java, solr, java-8, solrj, solrcloud

I have started playing around with solr6 to upgrade my current server version.

I tried to run the code on [here](https://sematext.com/blog/2016/04/26/solr-6-as-jdbc-data-source/) but when I run the code I am getting:

```
java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: First tuple is not a metadata tuple
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.sql.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:70)
    at com.sematext.blog.App.main(App.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: First tuple is not a metadata tuple
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.sql.ResultSetImpl.<init>(ResultSetImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.sql.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:67)
    ... 6 more
```

My code is

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;

    public class App
    {
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {


        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        try{
            String connectionString = "jdbc:solr://zkhost:port?collection=test&aggregationMode=map_reduce&numWorkers=1";
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
            statement  = connection.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select id, text from test limit 5");
            while(resultSet.next()){
                String id = resultSet.getString("id");
                String nickname = resultSet.getString("text");

                System.out.println(id + " : " + nickname);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if (resultSet != null) {
                try {
                    resultSet.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
            if (statement != null) {
                try {
                    statement.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
            if (connection != null) {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
        }


    }
    }
```

I tried to figure out what is happening, but there is no more logs other than the one above. And on Solr side, the logs seem okay:

```
2016-05-04 15:52:30.364 INFO  (qtp1634198-41) [c:test s:shard1 r:core_node1 x:test] o.a.s.c.S.Request [test]  webapp=/solr path=/sql params={includeMetadata=true&numWorkers=1&wt=json&version=2.2&stmt=select+id,+text+from+test+limit+5&aggregationMode=map_reduce} status=0 QTime=3
2016-05-04 15:52:30.382 INFO  (qtp1634198-46) [c:test s:shard1 r:core_node1 x:test] o.a.s.c.S.Request [test]  webapp=/solr path=/select params={q=(*:*)&distrib=false&fl=id,text,score&sort=score+desc&rows=5&wt=json&version=2.2} hits=5624 status=0 QTime=1
```

The related part which is throwing exception is:
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.sql.ResultSetImpl

```
      Object isMetadata = this.metadataTuple.get("isMetadata");
      if(isMetadata == null || !isMetadata.equals(true)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("First tuple is not a metadata tuple");
      }
```

with classpath:

```
solr-solrj-6.0.0
commons-io-2.4
httpclient-4.4.1
httpcore-4.4.1
httpmime-4.4.1
zookeeper-3.4.6
stax2-api-3.1.4
woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1
noggit-0.6
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7
slf4j-api-1.7.7
```

The error is happening because of some missing handlers on errors on the code or missing params for the query (suspecting "includeMetadata=true" part from the solr logs, and it is not there when I curl)? Anyone had similar issues while using sql with solrj?

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem appears to be the difference between the configs and formats of pre-6 versions of Solr.

After digging around for some time, with the help of the guys in the mail group, I have tried a totally clean installation, and changing configs manually rather than directly copying from the previous version's conf folder.